# How to get full T2?

Tags: spore

I am stuck with this:

[image: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/237x274q90/196/x23u.png]

How do I unlock it? Only I have is "Atmosphere Generator".
I don't want to use it, cause I haven't found another one and I am scared that if I use
it, it won't succeed to get it back.

@edit - I saved. Gone on planet, used that "Atmosphere Generator", it didn't do jack.

@edit 2 - It looks that atmosphere is too cold. How to make it warmer, without atmosphere gadgets? Because I can't find one in entire Cluster and even if I would find it, I wouldn't be able to buy 1 (there are about 8) for hmmm, 10 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice that the little yellow indicator is way on the left side; that means it's too cold to build any more cities.

You'll need to find some terraforming tools to raise the temperature.  If you can buy some Volcanoes or Asteroid Call items, you can use them to increase the temperature, while raising and lowering the atmosphere at the same time.  Since that's right where you want it, alternating their use would give best results.

If you can't afford them, there are energy-using items that last forever that do the same things.  For these, you're looking for the Hot Cloud Seeder, and Hot Cloud Vacuum, respectively.  You won't get those until you've colonized a whole bunch of planets, though.

You can find out more information about terraforming planets [here](http://spore.wikia.com/wiki/Terraforming).

Comment: I read this site already. But thanks for answering though. And prices of products doesn't seem to be that high though. 17K for 1 red spice. Terraforming things cost around 75-100K.

Answer (score 0):

Your planet is too cold, in order to upgrade its tiers the temperature/atmosphere must be close to center. In some planets its impossible to keep them stable in the center (if they are too close to the sun they will always heat up, and such). The color of the planet on the solar system info pane signifies its "natural" state (red planets will always get hot and blue will always get cold). Only green planets can be terraformed and kept stable.

Basic terraforming equipment (adding/removing atmosphere, cooling and heating rays) are all on your home planet after a short session of building outposts or [improving a planets T score](http://spore.wikia.com/wiki/Terra-Wrangler)s. More advanced versions like combination atmosphere+heat or a "perfecting beam" can be found later through exploring, trading, building outposts, and war.

Comment: I have a question. I looked up how much of red spice my planet delivers. It's says X/hour. Per hour. This is too much time for normal gameplay. Does spice collect over time, while game is off?

Comment: red spice collects only in-game, but its one of the cheapest spices in the game. Look around for the other types (pink is most expensive IIRC) and colonize them. trade routes don't do much. you are better off collecting the stockpile of spice and then selling it yourself. trade routes are merely for eventually buying out the star system.

Comment: Yet, you didn't answered my question.